# Is it possible to add energy to an antiparticle?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, antimatter

The title says most of it but the more drawn out version is. If you were to add energy to a single particle or antiparticle in a pair, what would be the effects, if it is possible to do.

Comment: Antiparticles are particles: they have the same mass as, but opposite "charges" than their corresponding particles. So yes, you can add energy to an antiparticle: it'll go faster (that's how accelerators work). But it's not clear from your question whether you are worried about a "free" particle or some kind of bound state (e.g. positronium)?

Answer (score 2):

Any given antiparticle is no more or less constrained in its motion or energy than any given particle.  One can simply add energy to them the same way that one does to the paired particle.

there seems to be a misconception here that particle/antiparticle pairs are inherently constrained by some sort of quantum entanglement to live in some sort of mirror state with each other, but this is simply not true.

Answer (score 1):

Energy is readily added to antiparticles in special particle accelerators called *colliders*, where beams of (for example) protons are steered into collision with beams of antiprotons after both are boosted up to tremendous energies. since their charges are opposite, both beams can be simultaneously accelerated in the same machine simply by running them in opposite directions.